# npgsql Connection Idle Lifetime performance issues

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I get the performance issues with npgsql library when below settings added in the connectionstring.

```
Connection Idle Lifetime = 2;Connection Pruning Interval = 2;
```

But ​the queries are much faster without these properties.​​​​

Comment: You are effectively telling Npgsql to close idle connections in the pool after 2 seconds - any reason you are setting this to such a short value? The default, which is 300 (5 minutes) is probably more appropriate.

Comment: I had default values, that resolved the problem @ShayRojansky